# Check the bits length of csr

Tags: openssl

Ive created an csr with onpenssl:

```
req -config c:\OpenSSL\openssl.cnf  -new -batch -sha256 -key private.pem -subj '/x500UniqueIdentifier=Hi' -out csr.pem
```

My question is how can i check the bits ouput length of this command with the key:

```
 req  -config c:\OpenSSL\openssl.cnf  -in csr.pem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

> req -in csr.pem -text

This will print out the contents of the CSR, including the bit length of the public key.